# Whats the equivalent of C# "Click.add" for Visual Basic .net

Tags: c#, vb.net

While exporting my program from C# to VB.net manually i faced this line of code:

```
        ctl.Click += ctl_Click;
```

Now this code is supposed to "add" an extra event to the event handler of the user control. (since the event of "click" wouldn't fire otherwise). However I couldn't find any equivalent events of either += or the .add for the vb. I saw some online topics about **AddHandler** but from what I saw it doesn't appear to be the same thing. Any suggestions?

Comment: `AddHandler` is the same thing. You'd write `AddHandler ctl.Click, AddressOf ctl_Click`

Comment: Have you tried look to at [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4)? See there are VB tab in example code, where you can switch from C# to VB example.

Comment: This post explains it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I see. So I was missing the "AddressOf" In the issue. To be honest I couldn't find that documentation at my Search but its probably because I wasn't sure of what I was searching for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB.NET you have to use `AddHandler` and `AddressOf` to attach dynamically events to control which works the same as the C# equivalent provided.

`AddHandler ctl.Click, AddressOf Ctl_click`

You can read more about this [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use `AddHandler`

```
AddHandler ctl.Click, AddressOf ctl_Click
```