# Clipboard.ContentChanged Event

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winapi

There is a [Clipboard.ContentChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.contentchanged?view=winrt-19041) event for tracking changes to the Clipboard

I tried to register a handler for the this event with the following code:

```cpp
Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.addEventListener("contentchanged", CtC)
```

But I get an error:

> addEventListener is not a member of Clipboard

How can I register a handler for the `ContentChanged` event and make an event handler in Visual Basic?

Comment: That is Javascript code, in vb.net you use AddHandler.

Comment: See [Events (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/events/) for how to define and assign event handlers in VB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whats the equivalent of C# "Click.add" for Visual Basic .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40169907/whats-the-equivalent-of-c-sharp-click-add-for-visual-basic-net)